# RewriteCond and regexp to prevent Hotlink

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

I'm trying to create a rule to prevent hotlinking but still continuing to accept google.

I'm trying

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google\.(com¦(co\.)?[a-z]{2})/.*$ [NC]
```

but it's not working. google.com, google.de, google.co.br, etc are still blocked.

Any idea what is the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is fine (the idea of it), but note, that you have a "wrong" character in the pattern:

You are using `¦` instead of `|` in `(com¦(co\.)`